# Java Spring AOP:Making advice work for PostMappings that belong only to certain classes in a package

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop, spring-aspects

Hello i am trying to apply logging to my app by using aop.At this moment i can apply the advice on all the PostMapping methods from the application by using this pointcut.

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
    public void postAction() {

    }
```

this is the advice

```
 @Before("postAction()")
    public void beforePost(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes())).getRequest();
        String name = request.getParameter("firstName");
        logger.info(name);
    }
```

i don't want this.i want the advice to apply to only the PostMappings that handle User Objects and i guess this refers to the 3 controllers that handle the postmappings.In this case my package structure is this.

```
src>main>java>com>example>myApp>controller>(the 3 classes i want are here:EmployeeController,StudentController,UserController)
```

How do i make this pointcut

```
  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping)")
```

apply only to the 3 classes above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about combining several pointcus; adding those to your existing one:

```
@Pointcut("within(com.example.myApp.controller.EmployeeController)")
public void employeeAction() {

}

@Pointcut("within(com.example.myApp.controller.StudentController)")
public void studentAction() {

}

@Pointcut("within(com.example.myApp.controller.UserController)")
public void userAction() {

}
```

Then, in your advice, you could use:

```
@Before("postAction() && (employeeAction() || studentAction() || userAction())")
```

Comment: thanks for answering, yes that would work if i wouldn't have other Controller classes in that package, but i do.I have 7 Controllers in that package and only want to apply the advice on 3 of them.Any ideea how to be more specific than that in my syntax?

Comment: after i added the code above i get the following exception :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpointGroupsBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource

Comment: [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut controllerAction

Comment: Hm... try destructing the logical sentence (I'm not sure AspectJ provides this syntax), eg. `@Before(postAction() && employeeAction() || postAction() && studentAction() ...`

Comment: Hei, now it works it seems i had a syntax error in my signiture, thanks alot !Could you please also upvote my post for some rep, i will upvote yours since it fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad to help ;)